# How to perform full text search and indexing using ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, indexing, lucene.net

I was looking at how to perform full-text searching and indexing similar to Whoosh in python.

I have looked at Lucene.NET but it looks like it's not compatible with ASP.NET Core (2.0 or higher).

Are there any other alternatives for a full-text search engine in this tech stack?

Comment: You can use fulltext search on SQL Server

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Entity Framework Core 2.1.0 introduced Full Text Search Compatibility using `FreeText` and EF Core 2.2.0 introduced `Contains`.

EF and LINQ using `Contains`:

```
string criteria = "Find This";

var items = Inventory.Where(x => EF.Functions.Contains(x.KeySearchField, criteria)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have the latest version of the .Net Core SDK (2.1.500) and I am not seeing the method "Contains". I only see "FreeText".

Comment: Sorry, `Contains` was introduced in EF Core 2.2.0
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/50b2296dfa89108dc7a5fcfea9537d978994f456/src/EFCore.SqlServer/Query/ExpressionTranslators/Internal/SqlServerFullTextSearchMethodCallTranslator.cs#L19

Comment: What is the difference if i use inventory.where(x=>x.KeySearchField.contains(criteria))  ???

Comment: As a weird behavior, we need to mention that Contains was introduced in EF core 2.X, in version 3.1.Y that one resolves only to IP addresses for Postgres EF provider.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this nuget package Bsa.Search.Core.

This package compatible  with .Net Core 3.1 and has no dependencies.

The library contains 3 index types:

- MemoryDocumentIndex - fast memory index
- DiskDocumentIndex stores the index on disk
- DiskShardDocumentIndex stores large indexes on disk of more than 3 million documents

Example of using Memory index

```
var field = "*"; // search in any field
var query = "(first & \"second and four*\") | (four* ~3 \'six\')"; //search word: first and phrase with wildcard or four- wildcard on distance 3 with six
var documentIndex = new MemoryDocumentIndex();// instance of new memory index
var content = "six first second four"; // text that is indexed
var searchService = new SearchServiceEngine(documentIndex);//service engine for working with indexes
var doc = new IndexDocument("ExternalId");//the document to be indexed and externalId
doc.Add("content".GetField(content)); // adding a new field: content
searchService.Index(new IndexDocument[]
{
  doc// saving the document to the index
});

var parsed = query.Parse(field); // parsing the text and making a Boolean query
var request = new SearchQueryRequest() // 
{
     Query = parsed,
     Field = field,
};
var result = searchService.Search(request); //
```

[Result will be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfDSJ.png)

You can use this nuget package Bsa.Search.Core but under .net core 3.1 or .net framework 472